# Ring theory convention

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, convention

Given $0$ in the integers, and a member $r$ of a ring $R$, is it a convention that the following is satisfied:

$0_{\mathbb{Z}}r=0_R$?

Note ($r+r+r+...+r$ (n times) is defined to be $nr_1$, where $n$ is an integer)

Comment: It may be worth stating it but I doubt that anyone would be surprised.

Comment: What else could be the sum of no copy of $r$?

Comment: It's kind of a stretch to call it a convention. Any abelian group has a unique structure of $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and for this structure we have this property.

Comment: @CaptainLama I haven't learnt about z-modules yet. But the relation holds nonetheless, right?

Comment: Remember that there is no central body dictating mathematical terminology.  Some is agreed by everyone, some is agreed by most, some varies a lot.  The only way to be sure is to check the author's definition or, if you are the author, then state what you mean.  E.g. mention whether you require a ring to have a multiplicative identity.  Some do and some don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We define $nr=\underbrace{r+r+\cdots+r}_{n\text{ times}}\in R$ for $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$, evidently $(n+m)r=nr+mr$ for $m,n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$. If we want this distributive law to still hold true for arbitrary $m,n\in\mathbb Z$, which we absolutely do, then we are forced to accept $mr=(m+0_{\mathbb Z})r=mr+0_{\mathbb Z}r$ and hence that $0_{\mathbb Z}r=0_R$, since there is only one additive identity in a ring. So the statement $0_{\mathbb Z}r=0_R$ is true, pretty much by definition.

Answer (score 0):

In complement to YiFan's answer, there is a convention that if we perform a sum zero times the answer is zero in whatever ring we are working in. Similarly, in an iterated product we perform zero times the answer will be $1_R$ if such an identity exists. These conventions make a lot of degenerate cases make sense in such formulas.